# communicating parent directive variable to child directive in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to build a simple show/hide directive based on elements transcluded into divs. I have a parent and a child directive. When the parent directive is clicked on, the child directive should toggle show/hide it's div. The toggle function sits in the parent controller and toggles the variable between true and false so that the child directive can show/hide.

The problem: the toggle function in the parent directive works correctly, however the child directive is not aware of the toggle variable changing when the parent is clicked. I am passing the ctrl to the link function in the child directive by using require. This way I can access the parent controller objects for showing and hiding. The toggle variable is visible by the child, but does not reflect any changes after the initial load of the page. When clicked, nothing shows or hides.

code:

```
angular.module('demo', [])

.directive('demoParent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-click="toggleTarget()" ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.toggleTarget = function() {
                this.openTarget = !this.openTarget;
            };
            this.openTarget = false;
        }
    };
})

.directive('demoChild', function() {
    return {
        require: '^demoParent',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.ctrl = ctrl;
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="ctrl.openTarget" ng-transclude></div>',
    };
});
```

Does the child need to add a watcher to the parent ctrl or is this a case of isolated variables once passed from parent to child?

Comment: `demoChild` is requiring the demoChild controller. If you need to access the scope of `demoParent` from `demoChild` you would need to require it with `require: '^demoParent'` instead.

Comment: Could you show your HTML as well?

Comment: Just changed it to demoParent, that was a typo on my end. I am not getting any errors on the requiring of the parent controller. It seems that the child is just not aware of any changes to the parent controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12521/) with your working scenario, you had an issue with the `this` functionality as well, except the `^demoChild` which you said was a typo. Once inside your function, the `this` was pointing to the scope, and not the controller as you expected, so this section should be amended:

```
controller: function($scope) {
    this.openTarget = false;
    var _ctrl = this;
    $scope.toggleTarget = function() {
        _ctrl.openTarget = !_ctrl.openTarget;              
    };              
}
```

Comment: That worked for me. How come assigning this to another var resolves the problem? Using this indirectly vs directly and passing it to the child.

Comment: @user3613538 `var _ctrl = this;` this line is required to keep reference to your controller, which you then use in the function. Otherwise, `this` points to the `$scope` itself, since `this`'s value varies - depending how you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
            var me = this;
            $scope.toggleTarget = function() {
                me.openTarget = !me.openTarget;
            };